# Is $\mathbb{C}^*$ not irreducible, or is every locally constant sheaf on $\mathbb{C}^*$ constant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am running into contradiction from the following set of definitions, propositions, and assumptions. Can anyone spot where I'm off?

**Definition** A sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a topological space $X$ is *flasque* if $\forall$ inclusion $V \subseteq U$ of open sets, the restriction $\rho_{UV}: \mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(V)$ is surjective.

**Proposition 1**: On an irreducible topological space, every locally constant sheaf is constant, since any two open subsets must intersect.

**Proposition 2**: For $\mathcal{F}$ flasque on $X, H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $i>0$. (Hartshorne Prop. 2.5 in Chapter III)

**Claim 1:** For $\mathbb{Z}$ the constant sheaf and $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ the locally constant sheaf on $S^1$, $H^1(S^1, \underline{\mathbb{Z}})=H^1(S^1,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$.

**Assumption 1:** The constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ on $S^1$ is flasque.

**Assumption 2:** $S^1$ is irreducible.

**Assumption 3:** The constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$ is flasque.

**Assumption 4:** $\mathbb{C}^*$ is irreducible.

Proposition 2 and Claim 1 give a contradiction.

I am guessing Assumption 4 is wrong (?), since locally constant sheaves on $\mathbb{C}^*$ are not necessarily constant? But I thought that $\mathbb{C}^* \cong \text{Spec }\mathbb{k}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is irreducible?

Edit: Now as I think about it, I think there's some issue with which topology is being used. For instance, Proposition 1 might require the Zariski topology. When we talk about locally constant sheaves on $\mathbb{C}^*$ not being constant, I think we're using the classical topology and considering $\mathbb{C}^*$ as a complex manifold. Any input would be appreciated

Comment: You need to clarify which topology you are considering. For example, C* is irreducible in the Zariski topology but not in the classical topology.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you good sir!

Comment: In general, if you have two nontrivial, connected, and nonintersecting open subsets $U$ and $V$ in some connected $X$ then the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_X$ on $X$ can’t be flasque. This is because locally constant functions on the disjoint union of $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$